# Convert Oracle Date into Crystal Reports

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports-2008

I am not very experienced with Crystal Reports, and I can't seem to figure out how to convert my Oracle date into a date I can use with Crystal Reports. Format field has it as a number. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few points that you must consider:

1. Oracle returns the date datatype column as a datetime object itself. This means when you do, for an example, a `SELECT birthdate FROM emp`, the birthdates of all the employees are returned as datetime values.
2. This data of datetime type can be handled by Crystal Reports as a value combining . If you want to format this data for display, look for Crystal Report's date-time formatting functions.
3. If you want to pass this date as a formatted string from Oracle to Crystal Reports, there is a wonderful function `TO_DATE` available in Oracle. This means, if you give a `SELECT TO_DATE('birthdate', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM emp`, the employee date will be of `VARCHAR2` type string, for example, `28-MAR-1987 21:40:13`. More about it on [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm).

So, it's upto you about where to format your date- in the underlying SQL statement or in Crystal Reports. You just have to Google a little further for your options in Crystal Reports. I have just given you the solution in Oracle SQL.

Comment: Rachcha - Thank you for your answer. I have an entire table connected to Crystal Reports that I don't really have a way (that I know of) to extract the data using SQL first to import into Crystal Reports. I wish I did, because converting the dates there (SQL) is something a little familiar with/have done before.

Comment: You just need to spend a bit more time on Crystal Reports and SQL. I bet there has to be a mechanism in CR to fetch data using SQL, otherwise it would be too difficult and inefficient to maintain complex reports in CR.

Comment: I found the Add Command option and finally figured out how that works and it seems to be doing what I want. I had to start over, but that is ok!